Boto3 Service S3 in lambda raising runtime error
I am running following code in AWS Lambda Python 3.11 with problems:
import boto3
region_name="us-west-2"
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
print("aaaa")
client_sm = session.client(service_name="secretsmanager", region_name=region_name)
print("bbbb")
client_ec = session.client(service_name="ec2", region_name=region_name)
print("cccc")
client_s = session.client(service_name="s3", region_name=region_name)
print("dddd")

It fails with service_name s3 with message (in Lambda Cloudwatch)
Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault.
I see all the previous prints, except, of course "dddd".

It does not reach maximum Memory, but anyway I increased to max memory.
Role running the Lambda and user associated to aws_access_key_id have both Administrator Policy permission.
The code works locally
putting the code inside try except does not give more debugging info, as it exits and does not reach the expcetion code.

What is the problem with service s3?

Side-note: You should not be providing an Access Key and Secret Key in your code. Instead, assign an IAM Role to the AWS Lambda function. This will provide it with credentials without having to handle it in your code. (This isn't related to your segmentation fault, I'm just mentioning it as normal practice.)

A minimal variant of your code works as expected.  Please update your code to an [mre] that fails, otherwise we will be unable to offer more than guesses as to what's going on.

This does not appear to be a valid Lambda function since there is no lambda_handler() function. When the Lambda function initializes, it will run all code 'outside' of the handler function, but when the function is invoked the Lambda service will specifically call the lambda_handler() function. Are you wanting this code to be part of each function call, or part of the 'initialisation' of the function?
